# How to split a html page to multiple pages using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a simple html file like this. In fact I pulled it from a wiki page, removed some html attributes and converted to this simple html page.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>draw electronics schematics</h1>
      <h2>first header</h2>
      <p>
         <!-- ..some text images -->
      </p>
      <h3>some header</h3>
      <p>
         <!-- ..some image -->
      </p>
      <p>
         <!-- ..some text -->
      </p>
      <h2>second header</h2>
      <p>
         <!-- ..again some text and images -->
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I read this html file using python and beautiful soup like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))

pages = []
```

What I'd like to do is split this html page into two parts. The first part will be between first header and second header. And the second part will be between second header <h2> and </body> tags. Then I'd like to store them in a list eg. pages. So I'd be able to create multiple pages from an html page according to <h2> tags.

Any ideas on how should I do this? Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the `h2` tags, then use `.next_sibling`  to grab everything until it's another `h2` tag:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))
pages = []
h2tags = soup.find_all('h2')

def next_element(elem):
    while elem is not None:
        # Find next element, skip NavigableString objects
        elem = elem.next_sibling
        if hasattr(elem, 'name'):
            return elem

for h2tag in h2tags:
    page = [str(h2tag)]
    elem = next_element(h2tag)
    while elem and elem.name != 'h2':
        page.append(str(elem))
        elem = next_element(elem)
    pages.append('\n'.join(page))
```

Using your sample, this gives:

```
>>> pages
['<h2>first header</h2>\n<p>\n<!-- ..some text images -->\n</p>\n<h3>some header</h3>\n<p>\n<!-- ..some image -->\n</p>\n<p>\n<!-- ..some text -->\n</p>', '<h2>second header</h2>\n<p>\n<!-- ..again some text and images -->\n</p>']
>>> print pages[0]
<h2>first header</h2>
<p>
<!-- ..some text images -->
</p>
<h3>some header</h3>
<p>
<!-- ..some image -->
</p>
<p>
<!-- ..some text -->
</p>
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you very much! :) Now I try to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Erdem: The `.next_sibling` attribute includes NavigableString objects (basically the text between elements) and the `next_element()` function skips those. Otherwise it's just adding each next sibling until you hit another `h2` or run out of siblings.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. Hopefully I'd be able to create web page using bootstrap template like your web page or learn.adafruit.com