# grouping text based on tags in HTML text

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, scrapy

I have a text which is in format of (keeping tags and removing the text for understanding)

```
<h2>...</h2>
  <p>...</p>
   .      .
   .      .
  <p>...</p>
<h2>...</h2>
  <ul>...</ul>
     <li> .. </li>
  ...
<h2>...</h2>
   <li> ..</li>
```

I am trying to use [scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919935/parsing-stray-text-with-scrapy) to separate/group the text based on the header. So as a first step I need to get 3 groups of data from the above.

```
from scrapy import Selector 
sentence = "above text in the format"
sel = Selector(text = sentence)
// item = sel.xpath("//h2//text())
item = sel.xpath("//h2/following-sibling::li/ul/p//text()").extract()
```

I am getting an empty array. Any help appreciated.

Comment: found an answer, I can do it using BeautifulSoup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444732/how-to-split-a-html-page-to-multiple-pages-using-python-and-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution, made with scrapy

```
import scrapy
from lxml import etree, html


class TagsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tags'
    start_urls = [
        'https://support.litmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/227739047-Sample-HTML-Header-Code'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for header in response.xpath('//header'):
            with open('test.html', 'a+') as file:
                file.write(
                    etree.tostring(
                        html.fromstring(header.extract()),
                        encoding='unicode',
                        pretty_print=True,
                    )
                )
```

With which I get the headers and all the content inside them

[image: header]